# GeoTools filters for shapefiles

Tags: filtering, shapefile, geotools

I am looking at using GeoTools to read shapefiles. The tutorial for using it is straightforward showing how to set a filter to "Filter filter = Filter.INCLUDE;" to specify everything.

I want to split up the reading for performance purposes on very large shape files. In essence I want to split the reading of the info in the DBF file from the reading of the "THE_GEOM" data. We have a lot of our own filtering already built and it is easier to just use it and then retrieve the actual geometry as required.

1. How do I specify a filter to retrieve all the DBF info without the geometry?
2. How do I specify a filter to retrieve the geometry without the DBF info? This isn't as important since it probably won't impact performance so much but I would like to know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By design the GeoTools' Shapefile Datastore goes to great lengths to keep the geometry and the attributes (the DBF stuff) together. So you are going to have to poke around in the internals to be able to do this. So you could use a [`DBFFileReader`](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/data/shapefile/dbf/DbaseFileReader.html) and a [`ShapefileReader`](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/data/shapefile/shp/ShapefileReader.html) to split the reading up.

I would consider porting your filters to GeoTools as it gives you the flexibility to switch data sources later when Shapefiles prove too small or too slow. It might be worth looking at the [CQL and ECQL classes](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html#cql-and-ecql) to help out in constructing them. 
If you are really dealing with large Shapefiles (>2Gb) then going with a proper spatial database like [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) is almost certainly going to give better performance and GeoTools will access the data in exactly the same way with exactly the same filters.